# C++ logging using ostream

Tags: c++, stream

I'm making a logger. I want to create a function `log()` that takes a stream as input.

For instance:

```
log("hello"<<" "<<"world"<<10<<"\n");
```

I also want it to be thread safe.

I've redefined the `<<` operator so I can do:

```
log()<<"hello"<<"world"<<10<<"\n"
```

But this operation is not thread safe.

How can I make it thread safe?

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, I'm not sure we can help you.

Comment: Oh, you just pass the `--make-my-code-threadsafe` option to your compiler.

Comment: Do you maybe mean "how to make that method chaining atomic/transactional"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have `log()` return a temporary object that buffers all output in memory.  The destructor for this object will run at the end of the expression, and should flush the accumulated data to the actual stream in a single atomic operation (up to you to make that operation atomic).

That will make your second syntax feasible:

```
log()<<"hello"<<"world"<<10<<"\n";
```

Comment: Note that to return a temporary object, the type must be copyable.  Unless you have move semantics, you need to simulate them somehow, so that only the final copy does the flush.  (You also want to take precautions to ensure that no exceptions escape from the destructor---it's more than conceivable that flushing a buffer could raise an exception.)

Comment: @James: Or just make the destructor for the copied-from object note that its buffer is still empty, and skip the flush.  Besides that, `log()` could itself be a constructor call, then there are no copies required.  The point about exceptions during flush is much more important.

Comment: `log()` could be a constructor call, but it's a lot more flexible if it is a function.  (At least, this has been my experience.  But my `log()` functions have generally done a lot more, inserting headers into the output, with timestamps, and so on.  Nothing that can't be done in a constructor, but sometimes it's more convenient to use the function.  And move semantics aren't too difficult to simulate, at least for what they're used for here.)

Comment: @James: Is the copy made during return formally inside the function?  In that case, there can be a private "copy" constructor (which may have move semantics) to which access is granted via `friend`.  And copies elsewhere are still prevented.

Comment: The temporary could be worked around if log() returned a type that was essentially `shared_ptr<BufferType>` with operator<< overloads (that just forward to corresponding BufferType methods).  The final flush occur in the BufferType destructor.

Comment: That's an idea.  I've actually had cases where I did want a local instance, in order to loop through a table, but one can argue whether that's a good idea or not.  The other thing is that in pre-C++11, binding to a const reference required a copy construtor (although I can't think of a reason why one would want to bind `log` to a const reference).  I'd have to go back and look at my actual uses; the more I think about it, the more I think that the constructor (which calls a helper function) would work, and the support for copy/move isn't necessary.

Comment: @mcmcc: I don't see the advantage in returning a temporary smart pointer instead of a temporary buffer.

Comment: @BenVoigt: My thinking was that if the caller did (accidentally/purposefully) make a copy of the returned value, then all copies would still write to the same buffer.  Now that I think about this further, this ability probably isn't that important.  In any case, the constructor solution is cute, but needlessly cute (IMHO) -- I would expect a common use case would be to only call log() once and cache the return value to be used multiple times within a function.  In fact, I would not accept a solution that did not support this usage.

Comment: @mcmcc: You'd store and repeatedly use the result of `log()` (whether it's a function or constructor) only if you intended all those uses to form a single transaction.  You definitely would not reuse the result if you wanted multiple events, even though they're going to the same log.  (Well, I suppose you could add a member function for explicit flush)  Even so, you can bind a temporary to a const reference, and it doesn't matter whether that temporary was produced by a constructor call or return value of a function.

Comment: Right, I haven't thought about this because I was using a singleton. I've just removed the singleton. Is there a way to do it with a singleton ?

Comment: @BenD: The log itself may still be a singleton.  What we're doing here is creating a temporary buffer, for accumulation of a complete log message, so that it can be written to the log in one atomic step.  If you don't buffer the whole message at once, you could interleave pieces of messages generated on different threads.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a function like the one you want. You can, however, create a macro that handles that stuff for you:

```
// "log" may be defined in the <cmath> header file
// so undefine it if needed
#ifdef log
# undef log
#endif
#define log(stream)          \
    do {                     \
        acquire_lock();      \
        std::cout << stream; \
        release_lock();      \
    } while(0)
```

You have to change the `acquire_lock` and `release_lock` calls to the proper ones for you. And of course use a stream that is appropriate for you as well.

Comment: why use `#define` when there is a beautiful thing called `class`?

Comment: @Default: Because you need textual substitution to get the left-to-right binding between the stream and the arguments, in the first example.

Comment: -0.3: You can create such function with a transaction proxy (I've done this myself to multiplex logging to several streams, some for colorful live output, some for file output, etc.). -0.3 for the hiding macro. -0.6 in summary. Makes no full downvote.

Comment: `#undef`ing `log` is *not* a good idea.  If you need a macro (which you don't, but you may want it for other things, like inserting `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`, **don't** call it `log`.  Use something else, like `LOG`.

Comment: @phresnel: There's no way to make the first snippet work without a macro, because `"hello" << " "` is undefined.

Comment: @JamesKanze Of course, but I just used the same name as the OP. Unfortunately the same problem will come up with a class/function named `log` as well.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It might.  If it does, the client code can always work around it, by using `std::log` for the function in `<cmath>`.  (But I'd go for a macro `LOG` using a function `MyNamespace::log`.  Logging is one place where macros shine, since they allow you to automatically insert `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`.)

Comment: @BenVoigt You need the alternative syntax: `log() << "hello" << ...`.  The function `log()` then returns a temporary which takes care of the rest... including an atomic flush in its destructor.

Comment: @James: I definitely agree.  You'll notice I put that in my answer.  But if it's necessary to also make the first syntax work (not clear from the question), then a macro can't be avoided.

Comment: @BenVoigt: True for syntax one, but Joachim didn't mention that he  emulates the first syntax only; the second can be transaction like, but Joachim said no more, no less than "not possible".

Answer (score 0):

in C++03 all operations are not thread safe

Comment: In C++03, the compiler never provides thread safety for you.  That doesn't mean that you can't use implementation-provided synchronization APIs to get thread safety.

Comment: In standard C++03, nothing is thread safe (and I know of at least one compiler which used static variables when stack unwinding an exception---which lead to some interesting results when two threads threw an exception simultaneously).  Many compilers do offer additional guarantees, however---a compiler can't be Posix compliant unless it does, for example.

Comment: @BenVoigt If the compiler doesn't guarantee some degree of thread safety, then you can't use it in a multithreaded environment.  See my previous comment about the use of static variables during stack unwinding.

Comment: @James: That still only affects "magic" behavior added behind the scenes, which isn't hard to avoid if you restrict yourself to an appropriate subset of C++.  It is a systems-programming language after all.

Comment: @BenVoigt The problem is knowing what the appropriate subset is.  Conceivable, a compiler could store the return address of a function in a static variable before pushing it onto the stack.  (I've actually used a Pascal compiler which did this, many, many years ago.)

Comment: @James: I suppose we'll just have to design something that works with a POSIX-compatible compiler, and let the odd really weird systems sort themselves out.